# SendMessage function to send text

Tags: vb.net, pinvoke, sendmessage

I have a form and on the form I have a web browser and currently opened google.com on  it.

Cursor is already focused on the search window. 
I have been trying to SEND search Text to WebBrowser control using `SendMessage` but not working. Current code.

```
Const WM_SETTEXT As Integer = &HC

Dim hdle As IntPtr = WebBrowser1.Handle

SendMessage(hdle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "test")
```

Why it's not sending text to google focused search tab ? How do I solve this ?

P.S : I don't want to use SendKeys or HTML method to SetText. I want to use Handler only.

Comment: How / When does the event for the SendMessage trigger?

Comment: Timer or  button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window handle of the Web browser control is not the window handle of the text edit control. So you are not sending the message to the control that you intend.

Indeed every mainstream browser that I know of does not use windowed controls. So that text window does not even have a window handle so no amount of work will make your basic concept successful.

What you are trying to do can best be achieved using UI Automation.

Comment: Can it be done using the SendMessage Keystroke ? Key up, down, WM_char ?

Comment: Where are you going to send the message, bearing in mind what I wrote above? And why would you send it? Input is placed in the input queue not sent. Faking input requires SendInput. But why oh why do you want to fake input when there exists an automation framework. We get tens of such question each week. Why are you so determined not to automate?